# User permissions for content in Django

Tags: django, permissions, content-type

I have this problem:
News website.
There are 2 types of content: Free and Paid.
There are 3 types of users: The user (and Guest) and the Subscriber.
The user can see free content. And can comment on the content.
Guests can see the free content. And Can not comment on the content.
The subscriber can see the free and paid content. And can comment on the content.
Monthly subscription.

Please give excellent solutions.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Please define criteria for excellent solutions

Comment: No items have been tried. I was looking for a turnkey solution for this.
For example here is: https://django-braces.readthedocs.io

Comment: [Django's auth app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/#user-authentication-in-django) has permissions, groups, and tools to restrict access to users with permissions. That gives you all the building blocks you need. There isn't a turnkey solution for something like this, since it depends on your views. Django-braces isn't a turnkey solution, it just adds more building blocks.

Comment: Hint: use 'user_profile' model, create a column user type and in views use if to check the user type and execute respective action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first i recommend you to use django rest_framework.it has many good tools for that and you can run your site in anyplatform that you want.its just a advice not related to your question.
 for your problem you have 2 ways first use the django document for underestanding what is the permissions model.with class Meta:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#permissions

second you can use the django app name : django-guardian

see the doc:
https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful.